# Correlation of elevation data and elevation uncertainty as a function of range in a DEM

Tags: correlation, spatial, uncertainty, variogram

I have a gridded Digital Elevation Model (DEM) which provides terrain elevation ($z$) at cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$. Together with the DEM I know the RMS of the elevations. As far as I understand the RMS can be applied to any point in the DEM and the standard deviation of the elevations is stationary.

Now, if I take two points from the DEM, the elevations at these points are not independent, but are auto-correlated if the distance between the points is below a certain range. I can build a variogram from the DEM elevation data which provides the function of elevation variation as a function of distance. For distances beyond the range the elevation variation is independent and just the mean of all elevations in the terrain.

However, what I really want to know is the uncertainty of the elevation at different close distances. I would assume that the uncertainty is equal to the RMS at large range, but apporaches zero if the distance apporaches zero. What I need is the function vor values between zero-distance and the range. I would just apply the variogram function of the elevation to the uncertainty and scale it from the mean elevation to the RMS, but I guess this is a pretty much simplified approach.

Comment: Because there may be some confusion in the question, let's address that first.  (I'm not saying you're the one confused :-).  Typically, an "RMS" is used to assess a "typical" error based solely on the $(x,y)$ location.  By employing a variogram, you are implicitly proposing using values of the DEM to *predict* its values at nearby locations.  But what is the point of that (except perhaps when the DEM has some gaps in its interior)?  "Applying the variogram" won't work; we're talking about the *kriging* algorithm here (aka the BLUP).